# Principle of Reverse Proxy with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I have a set of docker containers that each expose something:
Container A:1
Container B:2
Container C:80 (internal Website for LAN)

They are mapped to the host (IP X) and thus, visible to the local network. All good.

Now i want to make another website  (Container D:80) public to the internet. From what I understood from a security point of view is to have another host (IP: Y) that run a reverse proxy and only does the proxy and decides if to route 80 to Container C (Port 81) or to Container D (Port 82).

Am I corrrect or do I miss something? One could host the Reverse Proxy on the same host: Has that a higher risk to break out?

Comment: or you can run another web-server container as a reverse proxy to route traffic to your containers :)